# c++ 11 availablity for platforms that run java 7

Tags: c++11, operating-system, java-7, c++03

At work we develop software that uses java7 and C++03, I would like to get my team to replace c++03 and instead embrace C++11. Can I assure them that every OS that runs java7 has also a gcc compiler for C++11?

I know the relation I make between java7 and c++11 is somewhat weird, but that's my way of saying we need to support some old OSes, but not that old that they don't run java7.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whether you follow the sys specs for java 7 or not. There might be a way to force it to run on earlier versions of the mentioned OSs, but it is not officially specified so. take a look at the requirements:

[Java 7 & 8 Sys Req](http://java.com/en/download/help/sysreq.xml)

Now, for the listed OSs I am sure that GCC 4.7.2 is available (or it can be compiled). For windows, MS provides support for C++11 starting with VS 2010 which runs on Win XP or newer (if you don't like something like Cygwin).

The problem with all this is that it depends on how many C++11 features you actually need. For instance, Visual Studio 2010 doesn't support all C++11 features. Take a look at the following table to see what is supported in each compiler:

[C++ compiler support](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support)